# Uploading 10gb file to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm uploading this file into the cloud and seeing upload speeds of about 1.3MiB/s. Feel like this is very slow and there may be a better way but my company is very new to cloud computing.

I'm using google SDK to connect and upload via:

**gsutil cp [10gb file] [bucket]**

I've read about parallel uploads but fear the warning about needing some special crcmod.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: I've tried the -o GSUtil:Parallel suggestion and that did not speed up my upload. I'm doing this from my desktop which is routed through a VPN. I don't know if this has any consequences or how I could check if that might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to take a look at [object composition.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects)

As an example:

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp ./localbigfile gs://your-bucket
```

Some reading reference:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas

Comment: I will check this out. Since it recompresses it once it is in the cloud, does that mean I don't need a crcmod?

Comment: The crcmod is a different topic from my understanding, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CRC32CandInstallingcrcmod

Answer (score 1):

You are already got covered by `gsutil` which handles resumable uploads.

> Resumable uploads are the recommended method for uploading large files

> The gsutil command-line tool uses resumable uploads in the gsutil cp and gsutil rsync commands when uploading data to Cloud Storage.

Further details in this Google doc about [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads).